# Horizontal UIStackView - fix center item's size and stretch other items

Tags: ios, uiview, xib, uistackview

I am trying to achieve a layout like this:

[image]

Essentially, I need the `or` label to stay in the middle and occupy a fixed width and the lines to stretch out towards the edges of the screen.

Here's what I did in the XIB:

- created a horizontal UIStackview, with `center` alignment.
- Set the height constraint of the stackview to `20`, distribution to `fill`.
- added two `UIView` elements(for the gray lines), with a height constraint set to 5.
- Added a UILabel between the two `UIView` elements above.
- Added more constraints:
- left UIView leads with `0` from superview and trails with `5` to middle label
- right UIView leads with `4` from middle label and trails with `0` to superview.

Looks fine on the Interface builder, but on different screen sizes and landscapes, I find the middle "`or`" label to stretch and kick away the left and right UIViews to make up for the available space, which seems right:
[image]

If I set a width constraint of `20` on the middle label, the  right UIView stretches unevenly like this:

[image]

I know the CHP of the elements matters to some extent here, I have even tried setting CHPs like this:

- CHP of the middle label is 251
- CHP of left and right UIViews is 250.

This still leaves me with the uneven stretching of right UIView.

What is it that I am doing wrong? Insights much appreciated!
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't set any leading or trailing constraints...

Set "right view" width constraint equal to "left view" width, and give your stack view a `spacing` value of 4 or 5.

Storyboard:

[image]

Portrait:

[image]

Landscape:

[image]

Comment: this is the second time you've come to my rescue :)
Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 4):

You need to set `widthConstraint` on `UIStackView` and the make `leftView.widthAnchor = rightView.widthAnchor`. Alternatively you can set `leading` and  `trailing` constraints on UIStackView and then set `leftView.widthAnchor = rightView.widthAnchor`.

Below is the sample code you can try out in Playgrounds

```
    let leftView = UIView()
    leftView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    leftView.backgroundColor = .lightGray

    let rightView = UIView()
    rightView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    rightView.backgroundColor = .lightGray

    let orLabel = UILabel()
    orLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    orLabel.textColor = .black
    orLabel.text = "or"

    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [leftView, orLabel,  rightView])
    stackView.alignment = .center
    stackView.distribution = .fill
    stackView.axis = .horizontal
    stackView.spacing = 5
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(stackView)

    stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    stackView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
    stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true

    leftView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 5).isActive = true
    rightView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 5).isActive = true
    leftView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
```